# How to use mutate iteratively over multiple rows in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate the percent difference in ht between all possible pairs of data, per group of individuals, as well as the time difference between the ht measures. This is my data:

```
hc1<- data.frame(id= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
                  testoccasion= c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2),
                  ht= c(0.2,0.1,0.8,0.9,1.0,0.5,0.4,0.8),
                  time= c(5,4,8,5,6,5,2,1))
```

This is my code.

```
library(dplyr)
a<-hc1 %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   arrange(id,testoccasion) %>% 
   mutate(fd = (ht-lag(ht))/lag(ht)*100) %>% 
   mutate(t = time-lag(time))
b<-hc1 %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   arrange(id,testoccasion) %>% 
   mutate(fd = (ht-lag(ht,2))/lag(ht,2)*100) %>% 
   mutate(t = time-lag(time,2))
c<-hc1 %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   arrange(id,testoccasion) %>% 
   mutate(fd = (ht-lag(ht,3))/lag(ht,3)*100) %>% 
   mutate(t = time-lag(time,3))

diff<-rbind(a,b,c)
diff<-na.omit(diff)
```

I am curious how I can make this code shorter. I want to be able to find the difference across all possible pairs of ht, for all test occasions, where the number of test occasions differs between individual id's.It would be great if I didn't have to do it iteratively like this, because it's a huge dataset I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `map` to loop the `n` used in `lag`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(1:3, ~ 
            hc1 %>%
                group_by(id) %>% 
                arrange(id, testoccasion) %>% 
                mutate(fd = (ht -lag(ht, .x))/lag(ht, .x) * 100,
                t = time -lag(time, .x)))  %>%
  na.omit
# A tibble: 7 x 6
# Groups:   id [3]
#     id testoccasion    ht  time     fd     t
#  <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1            2   0.1     4  -50      -1
#2     1            3   0.8     8  700       4
#3     2            2   1       6   11.1     1
#4     2            3   0.5     5  -50      -1
#5     3            2   0.8     1  100      -1
#6     1            3   0.8     8  300.      3
#7     2            3   0.5     5  -44.4     0
```

Comment: Ahh thank you so much!! Just curious, what is the 1:3 at the beginning of the code?

Comment: @lokes That is the `n` used in creating `a` to `c` within `lag`.  By default, `n=1` so it is not specified in your code